# How to remove \n \t in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have HTML data which contains `\n\t`. I tried map it to `<br>` but it didn't work. And pre-wrap css also not working as well.

How could I remove line break tag?

This is my app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

function App() {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDatas = () => {
      axios
        .get('/api/data')
        .then( (rule) => {
          // get new rule
          const newInfoHTML = data.data[0].info;
          
          setNewData({__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(newInfoHTML)})
        })
        .catch( err => console.log(err));
    }
    
    getDatas();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <div style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={newData}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `\n\t` is newline + tab, possibly you meant `\r\n` (carriage return + newline)?  Could that be your problem?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what you mean 100%. My data is html tag string which contains \n and \t. I'd like to put this data in div without \n \t tag.

Comment: so string replace it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const newInfoHTML = data.data[0].info.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\t)/g, '');
```

```js
var str = "\n\t.. \n\t\t\t\t<p>Last updated: <strong>April 9,&nbsp;2021</strong></p>\n\n<p><strong>On this page:</strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li>";
      str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\t)/g, '');
      console.log(str)
```

Comment: I tried still won't work.. Still showing \n\t.. \n\t\t\t\t<p>Last updated: <strong>April 9,&nbsp;2021</strong></p>\n\n<p><strong>On this page:</strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li>

Comment: Hmm.. I added a snippet to my answer to demonstrate it...

Comment: I'm not sure why but I did \\n\\t it worked! Thank you for help!